# UIButton inside UIView extension

Tags: ios, swift

I was wondering how I could extend an UIView and handle the target selector of an UIButton inside the extension function, but I'm not getting it right. It simply doesn't respond to the target selector. I've even tried using a proxy disclosure. Here's the code.

extension UIView {

```
class ClosureDispatch {

    let action: () -> ()

    init(f:() -> ()) {
        self.action = f
    }

    func execute() -> () {
        action()
    }

}


func showMessageView(inView: UIView) {


    var isShowing = false;

    let height: CGFloat = 80.0;
    let paddingBottom: CGFloat = 20.0;


    var backgroundView: UIView  = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, inView.frame.size.height, inView.frame.size.width, height))
    backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.8);

    let close: ClosureDispatch = ClosureDispatch(f: {

        NSLog("go!")

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 0.5, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut, animations: { () -> Void in

            backgroundView.frame = CGRectMake(0, inView.frame.size.height, inView.frame.size.width, height)

            }) { (completed) -> Void in

                isShowing = false;

        }
    })


    var closeButton: UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(inView.frame.size.width-height-paddingBottom, 0, height, height))
    closeButton.setTitle("Close", forState: .Normal)
    closeButton.addTarget(close, action: "execute", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    closeButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()

    closeButton.userInteractionEnabled = true;
    backgroundView.userInteractionEnabled = true;

    backgroundView.addSubview(closeButton)
    inView.addSubview(backgroundView)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 0.5, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut, animations: { () -> Void in

        backgroundView.frame = CGRectMake(0, inView.frame.size.height-height-paddingBottom, inView.frame.size.width, height)

    }) { (completed) -> Void in

        isShowing = true;

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 3.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 0.5, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut, animations: { () -> Void in

            backgroundView.frame = CGRectMake(0, inView.frame.size.height, inView.frame.size.width, height)

            }) { (completed) -> Void in

                isShowing = false;
        }
    }


}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `@objc` in front of the execute method i.e. `@objc func execute()...`

See [this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH4-XID_39).

> If your Swift class inherits from an Objective-C class, all of the
>   methods and properties in the class are available as Objective-C
>   selectors. Otherwise, if your Swift class does not inherit from an
>   Objective-C class, you need to prefix the symbol you want to use as a
>   selector with the @objc attribute